# Why is `<=` and `>=` not related to `<`, `>`, and `==`?

Tags: ruby

When there is a method `==`, the method `!=` is defined to take that result and apply `!` to it. (And likely with `=~` and `!~`.)

Unlike this, `>=`, which conventionally means `>` or `==`, is actually independent of `>` and `==`. Either definition does not seem to affect the other (and similar with `<=`, `<`, `==`). Why are they designed to be independent?

**Edit** Broi Satse pointed out that in classes that inherit `Comparable`, there indeed is such relation. So my question would be restated: Why does that relation hold only for such classes? When would you want (in a non-`Comparable` class) to have `>=` work independently of `>` and `==`?

Comment: @sawa, are you sure, that `>=` means `== or >` and not `! <`?

Comment: @gaussblurinc Even if I define `<` on a fresh new class, the `>=` remains undefined. That means `>=` is not `!` on `<`.

Comment: @sawa it can't be defined 'as' magic, because such an ability for items ( as comparison and inequality ) are too narrow and should be defined ( by ruby design ) in some module with one generator-method `<=>` ( by ruby design ). There is a description of this model in @BroiSatse answer

Comment: @gaussblurinc By the way, in English punctuation, you should not put spaces inside parantheses.

Comment: @gaussblurinc Your comment above is just what I was suggesting. I don't get your point of writing it as if it were an counterargument to my view.

Comment: @sawa, `That means >= is not ! on <.` it could be true or false by design. You can write your own implementation where `>= is ! <` or where `>= is == or >`

Comment: `BasicObject` contains definitions for `==` and `!=` and they behave in the way that you described. However, it doesn't contain definitions for other operators such as `>` or `>=`. So, it's not like they're designed to be independent, the methods are just not defined.

Comment: @AmrNoman Maybe my phrasing may not have been very good, but that is what I mean.

Comment: I added a new answer when I intended to edit my initial effort, so I just deleted the initial one (the one you commented on).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a class is not `Comparable`, then it means exactly what is says, it is not comparable in usual terms.

In some exotic situation you may have operator overloaded in a way where `>=` does not mean `>` or `==`, but for example - is an operator to read a message from channel into a container

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

There is a module in ruby called Comparable (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Comparable.html), it implements all of those methods relying on a single method `<=>`.

```
class A
  include Comparable

  def initialize(a)
    @a = a
  end

  def <=>(other)
    @a <=> other.a
  end

  protected

  def a
    @a
  end
end

a = A.new(1)
b = A.new(3)

a < b
```

Because Comparable methods rely only on `<=>`, redefining `>` won't affect any other methods (as none of other methods relies on its implementation).

Comment: it is unrelated to question

Comment: That is what I have thought. But I had just learned that, even though `Array#<=>` is defined, `Array#<` and `Array#>` are not, which contradicts such claim. That is why I came up with this question.

Comment: @gaussblurinc - This is very much realted to the question - according to comments under the question, the question has not been understood.

Comment: @sawa - This is because Array does not include comparable. Just include it and all comparing methods will be available.

Comment: Thanks for your point. This a step toward what I wanted to know, but it does not fully cover what I wanted to know. I edited my question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer anyway. I upvoted this answer. It helped, but what I was expecting was an answer along Vasfed's. But your answer is very close to what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are asking why we don't have:

```
class Object
  def <=(other)
    self < other || self == other
  end
  def >=(other)
    self > other || self == other
  end
end
```

Use of `Object#<=` by an instance of class `K` requires that `<` be defined on `K` or on one of `K`'s ancestors. Same for `Object#>=`, of course.

If there is an underlying total ordering of instances (in which case `<=>` can be defined) I don't see any advantage of: a) defining `<` and `>` on the class and modifying `Object` as I have done, over b) defining `<=>` on the class (unless it's not already defined) and mixing `Comparable` into the class.

If there is not a total ordering, `<` and/or `>` can still be defined, but `<=>` cannot and therefore `Comparable` cannot be mixed in. If `<=` and/or `>=` are needed and are to be defined as I have above, having it done in `Object` would be a convenience.

Here is an example of defining `<` and `>` on a class that does not establish a total ordering:

```
class Range
  def <(other)
    first < other.first
  end
  def >(other)
    last > other.last
  end
end

r1 = (1..10)
r2 = (3..6)

r1 < r2  #=> true
r1 > r2  #=> true
```

If the two methods have been added to `Object`:

```
r1 <= r1 #=> true
r1 >= r1 #=> true
```

If something other than `<=` and/or `>=` in `Object` were desired, those methods could of course be overridden in `Range`.

I would think there would be situations where it would be desirable to define `<` and/or `>` on a custom class when `<=>` cannot be defined. In those cases as well, having the two methods in `Object` may be a convenience.

Note that if the methods were added to `Object` they would be overridden whenever `Comparable` were mixed in.

Answer (score 1):

> When would you want (in a non-Comparable class) to have >= work
>   independently of > and ==?

When you don't intend to use them for comparison for example. After all they are just method names[1], and nobody is stopping you from using them for whatever purpose you want.

[1] Though they are method names that are treated somewhat differently by the parser for their "sugared" forms (e.g. `foo < bar` instead of `foo.<(bar)`)